# Google Plus caching using etag always 200 Ok

Tags: google-plus

**Hi.**

Iam using google plus to get activities/public with guzzle (Curl).

My issue is that i always get 200 Ok back from google plus and not 304 not modified.

This is what i do now:

1) Sending a request to google plus and an ETag is returned.

2) After 1 min Iam sending a new request to google plus with this header: If-None-Match = ETag

**Details from the secound request:**

This is sendt: If-None-Match: RqKWnRU4WW46-6W3rWhLR9iFZQM/FN6sWAnVevumZIpkDnlRgcgn13o

The etag Iam sending here is from the first request I sendt. Where google plus returned this ETag.

**Header data returned by google plus:**

```html
(
    [Expires] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mon, 23 Feb 2015 06:13:44 GMT
        )

    [Date] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mon, 23 Feb 2015 06:13:44 GMT
        )

    [Cache-Control] => Array
        (
            [0] => private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform
        )

    [ETag] => Array
        (
            [0] => "RqKWnRU4WW46-6W3rWhLR9iFZQM/TibUAQj1vA8gnfLQlFV0m1uit-w"
        )

    [Vary] => Array
        (
            [0] => Origin
            [1] => X-Origin
        )

    [Content-Type] => Array
        (
            [0] => application/json; charset=UTF-8
        )

    [X-Content-Type-Options] => Array
        (
            [0] => nosniff
        )

    [X-Frame-Options] => Array
        (
            [0] => SAMEORIGIN
        )

    [X-XSS-Protection] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1; mode=block
        )

    [Content-Length] => Array
        (
            [0] => 32220
        )

    [Server] => Array
        (
            [0] => GSE
        )

    [Alternate-Protocol] => Array
        (
            [0] => 443:quic,p=0.08
        )

)
```

As you see there is a new etag and the feed is the same as the first request i sent.

This wil result in 200 OK Becuse the etag is not the same as the etag I sendt.

Though I see that some parts of the etag is the same: RqKWnRU4WW46-6W3rWhLR9iFZQM
(Everything before the / is the same. Iam dont know why.)

If you need more information don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Have you verified that Google actually sends the same etag when the stream has no changed (so it's not just a false implementation on their side)? That being said, I've had my troubles with Google Plus as they do not provide a public API (afaik) and scraping seems somewhat unreliable (some responses had malformed headers, for instance).